# extract values based on two columns

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I would like to extract a price value based on two other columns. In table 1, I am given the raw data where I want to draw from. In Table 2, I am given only the contract number, and I would like to find the type being "Mater" and have the price listed out for it.

I've tried to use this formula but I don't think I am calling the columns correctly.

=IF(AND(Table2!A1=Table1!$A$1:$A$6,Table1$C$1:$C$6="Mater"),Table1!$D$2:$D$6,"")

Is there a formula using index match, if(and), or another one that could work in this case?

Thank you!

Table 1.

| Contract | Work | Type | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5321a | aaa | Labor | 52 |
| 5321a | ab | Mater | 57 |
| 5641a | aba | Mater | 10 |
| 536451a | aae | Labor | 75 |
| 2441a | aan | Labor | 42 |
| 53421 | aar | Mater | 14 |

Table 2

| Contract | Mater Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 5321a | 57 |
| 5641a | 57 |
| 53421 | 14 |

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D2:D7,Sheet1!A2:A7,A2,Sheet1!C2:C7,"Mater")
```

(I'm assuming the first table in on Sheet1)

[image]